# WebSphere application server 8.5.5.13 - class files getting updated

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I recently migrated from WAS base edition v8.5.5.2 to v8.5.5.13. In fact I had to perform a fresh WAS v8.5.5.13 install as part of this migration. I had a OSGI application running on 8.5.5.2 and for any small code change, I used to perform the below steps -

1. Stop the server
2. Replace the class files under the folder \expandedBundles\Cba_bundle_name_folder\class_package_directory
3. Start the server
4. Test the new changes

This worked perfectly with WAS v8.5.5.2

However the same approach is not working with v8.5.5.13. Every time I replace the class files using the above approach and start the server (step 3), WebSphere is replacing the class files I placed with the originally deployed class files of the CBA deployed using WAS admin console.

Is there a way I can get the same behavior in v8.5.5.13 as was possible with v8.5.5.2? Any configuration changes?

I will really appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Thanks